# PHP & BigVideo.js, serving a video outside webroot

Tags: javascript, php, video

I am using BigVideo.js to place a background video on the page. If I use a video, which is inside the webroot, it works fine, no problems at all.

```
BV.show('http://localhost/sitename/web/assets/public/vids/video.mp4');
```

If I try to use a video outside the webroot, it will not play.

```
BV.show('http://localhost/sitename/web/app_dev.php/load/video/1/5/videoName.mp4');
```

I can put both of these urls into the browser and Chrome will play both video's fine. Therefore, I know that it is not with the path to each video.

I am wondering if it has something to do with the headers which are being set.

Here's my PHP code:

```
 $fileLocation = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sitename/app/Resources/userData/1/video/videoName.mp4';
 $file = new File($fileLocation);
 $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => $file->getMimeType(),
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="videoName.mp4"'
        );
 return new Response(file_get_contents($fileLocation), 200, $headers);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?